# Proving a useful identity with the Dirac Delta function

Tags: integration, dirac-delta

I am studying QFT and renormalization of QED, and in a passage is exploited the following identity:
$$\frac{1}{ABC}=2∫_{0}^{1} dxdydzδ(x+y+z-1)\frac{1}{(Ax+By+Cz)^{3}}$$
for every $A,B,C\in\mathbb{C}$.Does someone know how to prove it? I know it's just to compute the integral but I'm struggling with the fact that I have a finite domain. Should I use the step function?

Comment: What does $\int_0^1 \, \mathrm dx \, \mathrm dy \, \mathrm dz$ mean? Is that an integral over each of $x$,$y$,$z$ from $0$ to $1$? Or something else?

Comment: It's written in that way, In my opinion is just the unit cube domain. But I am not sure and I can't find anywhere this relation on textbooks

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_parametrization and links therein

Comment: Ah wow thank you!

Comment: But if ABC = 0 then both sides of the equation are undefined.

Comment: @DanAsimov Obvious !!!.

Comment: Yes, obvious, but contradicted by the statement of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Hereafter, $\bracks{\cdots}$ is an $Iverson\ Bracket$.
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\left. 2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\delta\pars{x + y + z - 1} \over \pars{Ax + By + Cz}^{\,3}}\dd x\,\dd y\,\dd z\,\right\vert_{\ A, B, C\ \in\ \mathbb{C}\setminus\braces{0}}}
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\bracks{0 < 1 - y - z < 1} \over \braces{A\pars{1 - y - z} + By + Cz}^{\,3}}\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = & \
2\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{\bracks{y < 1 - z} \over \braces{A + \pars{B - A}y + \pars{C - A}z}^{\,3}}\,\dd y\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over A - B}\int_{0}^{1}\left.{1 \over \braces{A + \pars{B - A}y + \pars{C - A}z}^{\,2}}\right\vert_{y\ =\ 0}^{y\ =\ 1-z}\,\,\,\,\dd z
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over A - B}\int_{0}^{1}\braces{%
{1 \over \braces{B + \pars{C - B}z}^{2}} -
{1 \over \braces{A + \pars{C - A}z}^{2}}}\dd z
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over A - B}\braces{%
-\,{1 \over C - B}{1 \over B + \pars{C - B}z} +
{1 \over C - A}{1 \over A + \pars{C - A}z}}_{0}^{1}
\\[5mm] = & \
{1 \over A - B}\ \times
\\ & \braces{\!\!%
-\,{1 \over \pars{C - B}C} + {1 \over \pars{C - A}C} + {1 \over \pars{C - B}B} - {1 \over \pars{C - A}A}\!\!}
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{1 \over ABC}} \\ &
\end{align}